# Emails not sending, PHP and SwiftMailer

Tags: php, smtp, swiftmailer, silex, mandrill

I have my code

```
<?php


namespace Spika\Controller;

use Silex\Application;
use Silex\ControllerProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag;

class SendPasswordController extends SpikaBaseController
{
public function connect(Application $app)
{
    $controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];
    $self = $this;

    // check unique controller
    $controllers->get('/resetPassword', function (Request $request) use ($app,$self) {

        $email = $request->get('email');

        $user = $app['spikadb']->findUserByEmail($email);

        if (isset($user['_id'])) {

            $user = $app['spikadb']->findUserById($user['_id'],false);

            $resetCode = $app['spikadb']->addPassworResetRequest($user['_id']);

            $resetPasswordUrl = ROOT_URL . "/page/resetPassword/" . $resetCode;

            $body = "Please reset password here {$resetPasswordUrl}";

            try{

                if(SEND_EMAIL_METHOD == EMAIL_METHOD_LOCALSMTP){

                    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                        ->setSubject("Spika Reset Password")
                        ->setFrom(AdministratorEmail)
                        ->setTo($user['email'])
                        ->setBody($body);

                    $mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance();

                    $mailer->send($message);

                }

                if(SEND_EMAIL_METHOD == EMAIL_METHOD_GMAIL){

                    $transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.mandrillapp.com', 587)
                        ->setUsername('me@me.com')
                        ->setPassword('89f7g8dfg8d7fg0');

                    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                        ->setSubject("Spika Reset Password")
                        ->setFrom(AdministratorEmail)
                        ->setTo($user['email'])
                        ->setBody($body);

                    $mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

                    $mailer->send($message);

                }


            } catch(\Exception $e){

            }

            return 'OK';

        }else{

            return $self->returnErrorResponse("invalid email");

        }

        return 'OK';

    });

    return $controllers;
}

}

?>
```

And I'm using [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/) along with SwiftMailer. The mail isn't being sent. I'm using [this](https://github.com/cloverstudio/Spika-Server/blob/master/src/Spika/Controller/PasswordResetController.php) for the code. It looks like there's something called Silex in there. It appears that the script isn't sending them since they do not show up on Mandrill. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try the mandrill api without swiftmail, its working for me